# Implementing HTML in Java file

Tags: java, html, parsing, tomcat

I have a Java file that includes a lot of validation messages. I have added some HTML tags (anchor link) in one of them as you can see below.

```
if (count > 0) {
  //Reg Path
  if (pCustomer.getCsnoemail().equals("N")) {
    errorList.add(new ErrorMessage(1, "Someone has already registered using that username. Try again."));
  } else {
    errorList.add(new ErrorMessage(1, "Someone has already registered using that email address. Please **<a href='/account/register-or-signin'> sign in here</a>** or try again"));
  }
  return new Logon(0, Logon.FAIL, errorList);
}
```

In the browser the html anchor tag is not properly intepretted. How can I make sure my html is read in the browser? I want this change to happen in the Java file itself and not create another html file and redirect.

Comment: The rest of the message is displayed?

Comment: I'm guessing you need to return your response as `text/html`, but you need to let us know: 1. Which framework you're using? 2. How you're sending back the response? 3. Which server are you using? Tomcat? Java is just a language, not a framework...

Comment: In JSF `<h:outputText escape="false" ...>`. Default is true.

Comment: Yes, the rest of the message is displayed but the html anchor link is parsed as text

Comment: What is the mimetype of your response?

Comment: I assume, I get that from my network tab in chrome. It says text/html for the page in question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well in the end I only had to use escapeXml="false"/ in my jsp and it worked